# Keyerror : 'count'

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly, bar-chart, data-analysis

I want to plot a interactive bar plot using plotly.express

```
state_count = df['state'].value_counts().head(10)
state_names = df['state'].value_counts().head(10).index

Bar_plot = px.bar(df,state_names,state_count, text='1',
                title='Top 10 states that have the most haunted places',
                labels={"y": "Count", "x": "States"})

Bar_plot.update_traces(textfont_size=12, textposition='outside', cliponaxis=False)
Bar_plot.show()
```

But I get an

> Keyerror: 'count'

I tried to traceback the error but unable to find any error and I tried to add `.reset_index()` but it generates a new error

> ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "KeyError: 'count'" occurs because you are trying to access a column named "count" in your DataFrame `df`, but there is no column with that name. The column name should be "state_count".

The error "ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()." occurs because you are trying to use the `value_counts()` method to get the count of unique values in the "state" column and then trying to use the result as a boolean value. This is not possible because the result of `value_counts()` is a Series object, which is not a boolean value.

To fix these errors, you can do the following:

- Use the correct column name "state_count" instead of "count".
- Convert the result of value_counts() to a list of values before using
  it as the y-values for the bar plot.

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

# Create a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'state': ['California', 'New York', 'Texas', 'Florida', 'Illinois', 'Pennsylvania', 'Ohio', 'Georgia', 'North Carolina', 'Michigan']})

# Get the count of unique values in the "state" column
state_counts = df['state'].value_counts().tolist()

# Get the state names
state_names = df['state'].value_counts().index.tolist()

# Create the bar plot
Bar_plot = px.bar(df, state_names, state_counts, text='1',
                  title='Top 10 states that have the most haunted places',
                  labels={"y": "Count", "x": "States"})

# Update the plot appearance
Bar_plot.update_traces(textfont_size=12, textposition='outside', cliponaxis=False)

# Show the plot
Bar_plot.show()
```